# FIle doesnt exist

Tags: ros, pcl

I am fairly new to ROS and Ubuntu.
I just followed the instructions as given on: https://pcl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extract_indices.html
I created a new folder called Extract_Indices in a catkin workspace called catkin_ws2
Then made a new file named: extract_indices.cpp
Then another file named: CMakeLists.txt -> Extract_Indices folder
I run the command: ./extract_indices

I get an error saying such a file doesnt exist.
I am not sure if this is a very simple question. But any help and patience is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you completed the step in that link that says "Add the following lines to your CMakeLists.txt file:"?

This might help too; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lU6RiS4pfE

Answer (score 0):

The website leaves out the command to actually build the executable. After creating the `CMakeLists.txt` from the website you need to run `catkin build extract_indices`

This is what actually builds your source code into an executable based on the contents of `CMakeLists.txt`